# Where is BDE for Delphi 10.4 Sydney

Tags: delphi, bde

Where are the BDE components for Community Edition Delphi 10.4 Sydney?  I looked under the Bin folder but didn't see them. Looking for dclbde270.bpl.

Comment: Per [BDE components in RAD Studio/Delphi/C++ Builder](https://support.embarcadero.com/article/44082): "*BDE has reached the final stage of deprecation, and **has been removed from RAD Studio**. You are encouraged to migrate applications to newer technologies like FireDAC. If you still want to install the BDE components perform these steps: 1. **Download the external BDE installer from your “My registered user downloads” section** ...*" In that case, I'm not even sure you can install BDE for the Community Edition.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the BDE components from [https://my.embarcadero.com](https://my.embarcadero.com/)

Comment: Hi, since BDE is removed from RAD Installation, there is no more Product Support, so the Link is out of date.

Comment: @Jens, I just checked and the page still lists BDE installers for Delphi 10 up to 11.

Comment: strange. Sometimes the Page leaks